# Отладка релиза вместо дебаг версии

Tags: c++, компиляция, visual-studio

Какие плюсы и минусы в отладке релизной версии вместо дебажной приложения на С++ под студией?

Comment: Релиз - это уже не для отладки, это финальная конфигурация программы, с максимальной производительностью. А вот смысл дебаг-версии как раз в том, чтобы ее можно было отладить.

Answer (score 7):

При отладке релизной версии будет больше "непонятностей" - компилятор может произоводить далеко не очевидные оптимизации, выбрасывать переменные, переставлять части кода. В некоторых случаях отладка может быть доступна только в ассемблерных кодах.

Но с другой стороны, в некоторых случаях, определенные баги (например, при многопоточном коде или из-за ошибок в компиляторе) можно понять, только если отлаживать релизный код.

Вывод: отлаживать нужно на базе дебажной сборки, она для этого предназначена. Релизную сборку нужно отлаживать только при необходимости.

btw: релизные сборки обычно отлаживают по логам и крешдампах.

Answer (score 4):

Хочу отметить, что ситуация не такая простая.

1. Отладочная версия программы обычно компилируется с определенными флагами и библиотеками, а релизная - с другими. Соответственно, они в принципе не могут быть идентичными. Хотя концепция такова, что в релизном коде нет лишних проверок и он оптимизирован. Некоторые оптимизации вообще могут быть опасны (например, компилятор решил, что Вы переменную не используете и убрал проверку ее состояния вообще из программы, а ее изменяет внешний поток).
2. Компилятор и компоновщик связей - тоже программы. И тоже могут иметь баги. Я лично сталкивался с ошибками в компиляторах. И что может намешать компилятор в объектном коде, тем более при использовании каких-либо экспериментальных возможностей - вопрос.
3. Отладочная и релизная версия программы отличаются особенностями выделения памяти и некоторыми другими моментами в поведении. Соответственно, возможен вариант, что в отладочной версии все переменные и указатели были инициализированы 0, а в релизной версии туда просто попадает мусор и программа, в конечном итоге, падает.
4. race conditions могут быть в обеих версиях программы. Очень обидно, когда код в произвольный, непредсказуемый момент времени падает. Но в релизе это обычно случается чаще :-) Тем более, что отладочную версию часто запускают под отладчиком, а он вносит свои коррективы в исполнение программы (в самое окружение, в котором она выполняется).

Касательно разницы в отладке - релизную версию по понятным причинам отлаживать сложнее. Это и потому что в ней включены оптимизации (некоторые функции будут отсутствовать, а будут встроены в код, непрямое соответствие между исходным кодом и машинным), и потому что будет отсутствовать отладочная информация (а она позволяет установить даже названия переменных и функций как они были в исходном коде).

Comment: 4. Проблемы в релиз-версии заметнее потому, что те, которые легче воспроизводятся в отладочной версии, ликвидируются на этапе разработки и первичного прогона.

Comment: @VladD, отчасти да.

Comment: Так может имеет смысл сразу отлаживать релизную версию? 
Плюсы:
- работает на порядок быстрее, актуально для больших проектов;
- программисты сразу начинают тестировать версию, которую будет использовать заказчик;
- параллельно можно запускать профилировщик.
Минусы:
- не весь код можно отлаживать, в таком случае можно перейти на отладочную версию;
- не работают assert и каких-либо выдача отладочных сообщений.

Comment: >  Плюсы: - работает на порядок быстрее

Если релиз работает на порядок быстрее, то это повод задуматься.

> актуально для больших проектов; 

для них другое актуально - быстрота компиляции. А правильная дебажная сборка будет собираться быстрее (компилятору не нужно делать лишнюю оптимизацию).

> параллельно можно запускать профилировщик

который затормозит в много раз код. Тестировать с параллельным профилировщиком - ещё то удовольствие.

> не работают assert и каких-либо выдача отладочных сообщений.

это обычно можно подстроить ключами для препроцессора.

Comment: > Если релиз работает на порядок быстрее, то это повод задуматься.

В дебаге работает куча проверок. Например, в STL проверка выхода за границы размера контейнеров и т.п. assert' ы и т.п.

> быстрота компиляции

Обычно при разработке нет необходимости часто пересобирать весь проект. Работа идет с небольшим количеством библиотек.

> который затормозит в много раз код. Тестировать с параллельным 
> профилировщиком - ещё то удовольствие.

Программа с профилировщик от VS 10 работает практически с той же скоростью, что и без.

Answer (score 2):

При компиляции релизной версии компилятор применяет ряд оптимизаций, призванных заставить ваш код работать быстрее. Но при этом может понизиться стабильность программы, и она начнёт вылетать. Именно для поиска места, где вылетает оптимизированная программа, и нахождения той оптимизации, которая это вызвала, и применяется отладка release-версии. В остальных случаях отладку производят под debug-версией. При создании debug-версии компилятор не только отключает все оптимизации, но и генерирует символьную отладочную информацию, которая помогает в отладке приложения. Эта информация не включается в релизную версию (так как пользователю приложения она не нужна).

Comment: Символьная информация обычно генерируется и для release-сборки (иначе откуда отладчик бы узнал о значении переменной, зная лишь её имя?), проблема только в том что не всегда можно установить взаимно-однозначное соответствие между исходником и скомпилированным кодом.

Comment: Очень интересное мнение про *"понижение стабильности"* программы и про то, что она *"начнет вылетать".*

Comment: @Котик: может, это у автора ответа проекция личного опыта? :-P

Comment: Рассуждения про стабильность в аналогичном вопросе уже были здесь (на Хэшкоде) года полтора назад. И практически теми же словами. Видимо это "цитаты" из какого-то пособия.

От себя же по этому поводу могу сказать только одно - как же надо так писать, что после оптимизации потеряет стабильность и начнет вылетать!

Comment: Вообще-то, если программа вылетает — это баг. То, что баг случайно не проявляется при каких-то условиях (например, в отладочной конфигурации), не делает его менее опасным. Наоборот, баг, который проявляется только при определённых условиях, _гораздо более_ опасен, так как вы не знаете, в какой момент он испортит данные пользователя.